# Inno Setup How to show network on a browse dialog?

Tags: inno-setup

In my setup, in the browser showed by a "Browse" button (`wpSelectDir` or `CreateInputDirPage` for example), a Network is never shown.

I've searched a while on this but I haven't found any solution for now.
Is there a way to show network and let the user select a network path?

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardly.

But you can re-implement the button using the [`BrowseForFolder` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_browseforfolder), which does show the network.

For example for the `CreateInputDirPage`:

```pascal
var
  Page: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure DirBrowseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Path: String;
begin
  Path := Page.Values[0];
  if BrowseForFolder(SetupMessage(msgBrowseDialogLabel), Path, True) then
  begin
    Page.Values[0] := Path;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page := CreateInputDirPage(...);
  Page.Add('');
  Page.Buttons[0].OnClick := @DirBrowseButtonClick;
end;
```

Comment: Hey, very thanks to you!
How could I not have thought of that before?
Pretty clean and quick solution ;)