# Inno Setup - Opening directory browse dialog from another dialog without hiding it

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using this code: [Inno Setup - How to create a custom form that allows me to locate the files to decompress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145316/inno-setup-how-to-create-a-custom-form-that-allows-me-to-locate-the-files-to-d/44214348?noredirect=1#comment75503426_44214348) How to open directory browse dialog from another dialog without hiding it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog opened by [`BrowseForFolder`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_browseforfolder) function is unfortunately implemented to have the `WizardForm` as an owner window. That effectively moves all other opened dialogs behind the `WizardForm`, while the "browse" dialog is showing (note that the dialogs are not hidden, they are just obscured by the `WizardForm`).

---

What you can do:

- Re-implement `BrowseForFolder` from scratch. That's a huge task.
- You can use [`CreateInputDirPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputdirpage) instead of your solution, what I have suggested you at the very beginning at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44145316/850848).
  For an example, see [Inno Setup How to show network on a browse dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39096540/850848)
  Though I must admit, that now that I understand, that you need to allow different files in different folders, this is maybe not the best solution anymore.
- As a workaround, you can abuse a different browse dialog implementation by the [`TInputDirWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputDirWizardPage), that does not suffer the problem of the `BrowseForFolder`:

  ```pascal
  var
    FakePage: TInputDirWizardPage;

  procedure BrowseForFolderEx(var Directory: String);
  begin
    FakePage.Values[0] := Directory;
    FakePage.Buttons[0].OnClick(FakePage.Buttons[0]);
    Directory := FakePage.Values[0];
  end;

  procedure InitializeWizard();
  var
    NewFolderName: string;
  begin
    NewFolderName := SetupMessage(msgButtonNewFolder);
    FakePage := CreateInputDirPage(wpWelcome, '', '', '', False, NewFolderName);
    FakePage.Add('');
  end;

  function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := (PageID = FakePage.ID);
  end;
  ```

  Use `BrowseForFolderEx` instead of `BrowseForFolder`.

  ```pascal
  procedure SelectFileBrowseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    Dir: string;
  begin
    Dir := GetSelectFilePath;
    BrowseForFolderEx(Dir);
    SelectFilePathEdit.Text := AddBackslash(Dir);
  end;
  ```

  [image]